# Cannot access keys by index with OPENJSON

Tags: json, t-sql, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

In SQL, how do I extract the value of a key by index `[0]`?  OR, what is the best way to extract a value from this JSON structure?

```
declare @jsonString nvarchar(max)

set @jsonString = '{
"action": "edit",
"data": {
    "Accountable Inventory Technician|99999": {
        "PosTitle": "Accountable Inventory TECH",
        "Publish": "true"
    }
}
}'
```

This will get me the name of the keys, "action" and "data":

```
select [key]
from OPENJSON(@jsonString, '$')
```

This will get me the value of the first key under Data "Accountable Inventory Technician...":

```
select *
from OPENJSON(@jsonString, '$.data')
```

**I cannot get the value of "action"**.  This returns nothing:

```
select *
from OPENJSON(@jsonString, 'lax $.action')
```

**I cannot reference by index**. This returns nothing :

```
select *
from OPENJSON(@jsonString, '$.data[0].PosTitle')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In SQL, how do I extract the value of a key by index [0]? OR, what is
>   the best way to extract a value from this JSON structure?

JSON index is used for arrays. For example, if your JSON has `["some","values","in","an","array"]` then referencing the [0] item will have the `"some"` value.
Your example doesn't have an array so you won't be able to access it that way.

> I cannot get the value of "action".

Using `JSON_VALUE` you can access specific items in your object:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@jsonString, '$.action') [action];
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@jsonString, '$.data."Accountable Inventory Technician|99999".PosTitle') PosTitle;
```

If your JSON is stored in a table, you can access it with `OPENJSON` and `CROSS APPLY`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #json 
CREATE TABLE #json (JsonString NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT #json SELECT '{
    "action": "edit",
    "data": {
        "Accountable Inventory Technician|99999": {
            "PosTitle": "Accountable Inventory TECH",
            "Publish": "true"
        }
    }
    }'

SELECT * FROM #json j
CROSS APPLY
OPENJSON(j.JsonString)
WITH
    (
        [Action] varchar(255) '$.action',
        PosTitle varchar(255) '$.data."Accountable Inventory Technician|99999".PosTitle'
    );
```

Comment: So I should have been using JSON_VALUE instead?!  Thank you!!  So much easier!  I'm dealing with strings (no tables).  I need to reference the `'$.data."Accountable Inventory Technician|99999"` key, but it's variable, and I won't know its name.  Is there a way to reference the first key under `data`?  Something like `select json_value(@jsonString, '$.data.["key[0]"].PosTitle')`?  OR, there's no way without an `[array]`?  Will I have to restructure the JSON?

Comment: Do you care about the Key name as well or only the value of `"Accountable Inventory Technician|99999"`?

Comment: At the moment, I only care about getting the values of PosTitle, and Publish.  I don't know how to do that when he parent object could have a different name.  `"Accountable Inventory Technician|99999"`, `"Another Job Title|87699"`

Comment: If you have control over the JSON structure, I would flatten out everything I could and access it by `$.keyName` always (unless of course you have a need for arrays or nested objects). You could try something like this: `SELECT final.[key] yourDynamicKey, json_value(final.value, '$.PosTitle') PosTitle 
 FROM #json j
CROSS APPLY
OPENJSON(j.JsonString) ref
CROSS APPLY 
OPENJSON(ref.value) final
WHERE ref.[key] = 'data'` with your current structure.

Comment: [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4073/sql-server-2016-advanced-json-techniques--part-1/) is a good place to learn about your options.

Comment: Agreed.  You, my boss, and myself think it's best to flatten out and simplify the JSON structure.  It'll make parsing easier on the SQL side.  Thank you for the love.